# Specify PhantomJS command line optionsto Selenium PhantomJSDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Does the PhantomJS driver support command line arguments?  I need to run Selenium tests with the PhantomJS driver and disable web security. I have tried:

```
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();           
options.AddAdditionalCapability("web-security",false);             
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\drivers", options);
```

but this does not seem to work. Does the PhantomJSDriver allow for passing command line arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify PhantomJS' `--web-security` command line options using [PhantomJSDriverService.WebSecurity Property](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/PhantomJS/PhantomJSDriverService.cs#178), rather than pass it as `PhantomJSOptions`.

This is added in Selenium 2.32.0, a quote from CHANGELOG:

> (on behalf of GeoffMcElhanon) Added support to pass arguments to
>   PhantomJS.    The PhantomJSDriverService now has type-safe properties
>   for all of the    command-line switches supported by PhantomJS. These
>   can be passed directly    on the command line, or can be serialized
>   into a JSON file for passing with    the --config command line switch
>   to PhantomJS.

Below is the untested code, please refer to the documentation (the WebDriver.chm in your Selenium zip file) when necessary.

```
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\drivers");
service.WebSecurity = false;
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

`PhantomJSDriverService` has other pre-defined command line arguments one can specify, please check documentation. Also 
there are methods to add your own arguments.

> **AddArgument():** Adds a single argument to the list of arguments to be appended to the PhantomJS.exe command line.
>   **AddArguments(IEnumerable):** Adds arguments to be appended to the PhantomJS.exe command line.
>   **AddArguments(String[]):** Adds arguments to be appended to the PhantomJS.exe command line.

Comment: Y'know that thing where a question gets asked on a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/QBUGtKBHMOA) and on StackOverflow, and you answer the one on the mailing list, and someone else puts an answer suspiciously like yours on StackOverflow? Yeah, that.

Comment: @JimEvans: Oops, sorry Jim, apparently I'm not a guy that checks mailing list regularly, which means I didn't know what your answer look like at all, but it's good to know now that my answer is identical with the JimEvans' "always correct" answer. Probably I should start stalking you on mailing list from now. Anyway, thank you Jim.

Comment: The PhantomJSDriver service  does not support AddArgument() or AddArguments()...Not according to the documentation http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

Comment: @user2474653: Please refer to the source code or the .chm file that comes inside the release package. This is the new feature in 2.32.0, while the online documentation is only 2.29.1. You don't need this anyway, I added this purely for someone else looking alternative solutions.

Comment: I have tried the code and neither solution works. I am using selenium 2.33. PhantomJSDriverService and PhantomJSOptions fail to allow you to disable websecurity. Another solution?