# Selenium phantomjs webdriver, how do I use sessions?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I start `phantomjs`:

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverpath);
```

I perform a series of selenium commands to login website, submit firms, verify Page etc.

Once logged in, can I start the webdriver again and reuse the same browser user logged session again so that I don't need to login again? How would I use sessions for phantomjs in selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain phantomjs there is the command line flag `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt` which can be used to persist the session cookie and use it in the next invocation.

The .net API provides the same functionality through the [PhantomJSDriverService class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_PhantomJS_PhantomJSDriverService.htm). This is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17797635/1816580).

```
DriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverpath);
service.CookiesFile = "path/to/cookies.txt";
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

The cookies will be automatically saved into this file.

If you want to have a little more control, then you should save the session cookie from `window.document.cookie` using [`driver.ExecuteScript`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_ExecuteScript.htm) into a file and retrieve it later.

Comment: does the cookiefile need to be stored in a cookie file? can store in database? its just a string right?

Comment: Yes, but I guess, the problem is that using it through `service.CookiesFile`, you would need a file. With `window.document.cookie` you can dynamically store and retrieve without falling back to a file.

Comment: I'll just use a file, :)

Comment: how do I reuse cookies for next session?

Comment: @Toolkit Specify the cookies file for the initial run and specify it again for the future runs. That is enough. Note that sometimes webpages show some kind of message that cookies are disabled. This is misleading, because they are always enabled, but there are other issues such as same-origin issues.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I used http://www.whatarecookies.com/cookietest.asp, it tells me every time I have new session when I make a screenshot

Comment: @Toolkit Cookies are enabled by default in PhantomJS. This answer has nothing to do with enabling or disabling cookies. If you have trouble, you should post a question. Please don't post comments on an unrelated issue.

Comment: my question is related, your answer doesn't work for session cookies

Comment: @Toolkit I see what you mean. It looks like the site's cookies are set using JavaScript. That might take a while. Have you checked that you're not exiting too early before the cookie is set?