# How to start PhantomJS with commandline options in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, webdriver, phantomjs

I can't find how to start phantomjs with command-line options like `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt` and other...

Tried `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('--cookies-file=/tmp/ph_cook.txt')` but nothing.

For unknown reason `add_cookie` don't work to keep logged.

I tried to start phantomjs like this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = "phantomjs --cookies-file=/tmp/ph_cook.txt --webdriver")
```

but getting error:

```
raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to start phantomjs with ghost driver.
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17788223/3124333 ?

Comment: @SiKing Wrong language, but I also haven't found the duplicate yet. There must be though.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It's all Selenium, the language bindings should not matter?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass commandline arguments to the PhantomJS instance behind the scenes by passing them as a list to the `service_args` argument:

```
webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--cookies-file=/tmp/ph_cook.txt'])
```

If the driver cannot be started then the language bindings are probably not able to determine the location of the PhantomJS executable properly. You may need to additionally pass the complete path to the `executable_path` argument. Note that if you installed PhantomJS through npm, the actual executable is not directly in the global package directory but in a subfolder of it.

Comment: Is there any way to do this when using webdriver.Remote? In other words, if I have phantomJS running on seleniumhub, can I pass it a proxy? webdriver.Remote does not take service_args as a parameter