# How Can I Debug PhantomJS Javascript Tests?

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs

I am using Selenium and PhantomJS to do integration testing on my web app.

When something goes wrong, how do I debug the Javascript?

Can I connect with Firefox Developer Tools using Valence?

Note: I already save a screenshot and the page source when the test fails. What I want to do now is set break points and step through the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to use [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for that. However, I'd recommend using an actual browser for debugging. PhantomJS is a headless browser, and well suited for the job when you need a non-intrusive and fast browser, but otherwise I don't see any point in using it.

### EDIT

Just looked at the [PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html), and found this:

> ### Remote Debugging
>
> Remote debugging permits inspection of the script and web page via another WebKit-based browser (Safari and Chrome). This is achieved by launching PhantomJS with the new option, as in this example
>
> ```
> phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 test.js
> ```
>
> After that, open Safari/Chrome/Chromium and go to the URL http://ipaddress:9000. If you executed the phantomjs command on the same machine, it will be http://127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: I saw that too but I can't work out how to set it when using Selenium to launch PhantomJS

Comment: Then perhaps your question should be how to [Specify PhantomJS command line options to Selenium PhantomJSDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788223/specify-phantomjs-command-line-optionsto-selenium-phantomjsdriver).

Comment: Also, not that debugging is currently broken in PhantomJS 2, so use the latest 1.9.8 version to remote-debug.

Comment: *I'd recommend using an actual browser for debugging* which is great until phantomjs reacts differently to the browser your debugging with...